# sort string array in c, but program crashes

Tags: c

I'm looping through a file to find matching records for a user input, then I need to print them in an ascending order. My program keeps crashing. I need help please. I've written a few functions to do the work.

```
static int myCompare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return strcmp (*(const char **) a, *(const char **) b);
}

void sort(const char *arr[], int n)
{
    qsort (arr, n, sizeof (const char *), myCompare);
}

void search_contact() {
    FILE * fp;
    bool found = false;
    char *records;
    fp = fopen("contact.txt", "r");
    system("cls");
    printf("\t*****SEARCH CONTACT*****");
    printf("\n\t Enter Mobile: ");
    char mobile[20];
    scanf("%s", mobile);
    char mobile1[20], name[20];    
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s %s", name, mobile1) != EOF) {
        if (strcmp(mobile, mobile1) == 0) {
            records = malloc(sizeof(name));
            strcpy(records,name);

            int i;
        //  printf(" %s", records);
            found = true;
        } else {
            found = false;
        }
    }
    if(found){
        int n = sizeof(records)/sizeof(records[0]);
         sort(records, n);
         int i;
         for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%s \n", records[i]);
    }
    else{
        printf("\n No Records Found!");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\n\tPRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE");
    getch();
    main();
}
```

Comment: why u calling main, it should be entry point

Comment: I'm calling main() because it displays a menu that the user will choose an option from, and for each option I've made a case to call the required functions

Comment: `records` is a single `char *` and `sort()` is sorting an array of `char *`.  `while (fscanf...` loop leaks memory.

Comment: `records = malloc(sizeof(name));` ==> `records = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);`

Comment: Tip: try to get code working first without the `sort()` call.

Comment: Your code is not really compilable and testable as it stands [mcve]. However from what's presented, your program structure is way off base, the menu in *main* should be wrapped in a loop to display it over and over again, right now you are probably smashing the call stack because of deeper and deeper calls.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think OP needs a `char **records` to "to find matching records for a user input,"  - a list of strings.

Comment: `while (fscanf(fp, "%19s %19s", name, mobile1) == 2) {` makes more sense than `while (fscanf(fp, "%s %s", name, mobile1) != EOF) {`.  Why continue if only 1 string was scanned?

Comment: When posting, including your input, output seen and output expected is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You want `records` to be an array of strings, so it should be:

```
char **records = NULL;
int num_records = 0;
```

Then, when you add a string to the records array:

```
records = realloc(records, sizeof(*records) * (num_records + 1));
if (NULL == records) { // Handle failure }
records[num_records] = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
if (NULL == records[num_records]) { // Handle failure }
strcpy(records[num_records], name);
num_records += 1;
```

And don't forget to `free()` all that data.